Spring batch ItemWriter Insert into two related table fail
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "table2 violates foreign key constraint "tab1_tab2_FK"
Hello,
I'm trying to insert into an ItemWriter in two related tables.
Table1 and table2, table 2 contains a foreing key from table 1.
in the write function of my writer I execute two jdbcTeplate. update (one to insert into table 1 and the second for table 2)
I have chunk = 100.
I have a constraint violation exception because foreing keys are persisted before their parents.
Here is the Write function of my writer:
@Override
@Transactional
public void write(List<? extends ProcessorOutput> items) throws Exception {

    List<ProcessorOutput> itemList = (List<ProcessorOutput>) items;

    List<MyTab1Dto> itemsTab1 = itemList.stream().map(item -> item.getMyTab1Dto()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    int[] tab1InsertReturn = jdbcTemplate.
            batchUpdate(requestTab1Insert, new Tab1BatchInsertPreparedStatementSetter(itemsTab1));

    List<MyTab2Dto> itemsTab2 = itemList.stream().map(item -> item.getMyTab2Dto()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    int[] tab2InsertReturn = jdbcTemplate.
            batchUpdate(requestTab2Insert, new Tab2BatchInsertPreparedStatementSetter(itemsTab2));

}

